# Reusable query function based on args in prisma

Tags: typescript, prisma, prisma2

Is there a way to create a reusable query function for prisma?

Something like this:

```
async function getData(tableName: string) {
  const data = await prisma[tableName].findMany({});
  await prisma.$disconnect();
  return data;
}
```

And then pass in a tableName when invoking the function